# Downcase before save is nil is Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Rails 5.0.0.rc1**

I want to have the `username` to `downcase` before save in rails 5.0.0.rc1 but some how `username` is `nil`:

user.rb:

```
before_save :downcase_username

def downcase_username
  self.username.downcase!
end
```

Html:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username" />
</form>
```

> undefined method `downcase!' for nil:NilClass

I'm using React and I can create a user with a username no problem. I could have the `username` set to `toLowerCase` but I choose not to.

Why username is nil?

**Edit (.jsx):**

```
handleName: function(e){
  this.setState({name: e.target.value});
}

<form action="/users" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username"
    value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName} placeholder="username" />
  <button className="button small radius" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

**Devise controller:**

```
def create
    super do |resource|
      resource.user[username] = params[:username]
      resource.registration_id = params[:registration_id]
      resource.save!
    end
  end
```

Logs:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"Test", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration_id"=>"2"}
Unpermitted parameter: username
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 159ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

**Logs 2:** # Data now saves but still getting downcase is nil

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-05 17:18:10 +0100
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"Foo", "email"=>"foo@example.edu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration_id"=>"2"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "foo@example.edu"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "foo@example.edu"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$TrrnP4391MeEMvn8e2JwMesU5JS0vGELx0.8eUVO.B4sDPZVdUFMy"], ["created_at", 2016-06-05 16:18:10 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-06-05 16:18:10 UTC], ["username", "foo"]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 168ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
```

Comment: @7urkm3n Tried but it's the same

Comment: You could avoid that exception by ensuring that the attribute is present: `self.username.downcase! if username.present?` But that wouldn't solve the problem that the attribute is not set in the first place. To help you with that we need more information: Can you please post: You view, the code to send the form, the params received by the app and your controller?

Comment: @7urkm3n Same. I'll update the post with my actual code.

Comment: @Sylar can u post yr server log after commit to post ?

Comment: @7urkm3n Ok. I have updated the post. That should work.

Comment: I guess you have a `user_params` method in your controller, how does it look like? Do you permit the `username` in that method?

Comment: @Sylar update yr params in controller man )))) `params.require(:user).permit(:username)`

Comment: I'm using Devise. Where to put that?

Answer (score 1):

Update your method on `user.rb` to as per below:

```
def downcase_username
  self.usernname = self.username.try(:downcase)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protected
      def configure_permitted_parameters
        # from new devise -v 4.1.1 gem
        # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
        # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])

         #older version
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:username]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:username]
      end
end
```

Comment: Im on Rails 5.0.0.rc1 and same error. But now...it is saving! Huh? Why the error?

Comment: @Sylar do u have `username` column in users table ? also you dnt need override `create` method. just add my post like it.

Comment: Yes. It all works before I want to downcase before save.

Comment: this one not works ?`before_save { self.username = username.downcase }` or `before_save { |u| u.username = username.downcase }`

Comment: Yep. Same error although it saved in the db but not the session. Maybe a bug with Rails 5 as with Rails 4, no issue.

Comment: where session came from ?

Comment: When a new user is created, it should log the user in. What happen is, the user is created then the error.

Comment: can u post that server log too. what error is that.

Comment: See logs 2. I'm all out of ideas. In my controller: `skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: ok. because I am lazy, I have moved the `downcase` to the registration controller. problem solved.